# При изменении ширины экрана блок не меняет размер

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, media-queries, адаптивность

При изменении ширины страницы (менее 992px) должен пропадать блок (adds), а соседний (content) должен растягиваться на всю ширину.

Я пробовал через медиа-запрос увеличивать ширину, но блок остаётся того же размера - 70%

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .adds {
    display: none;
  }
  .content {
    /* это не помогает, ширина остаётся такая же  */
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.content {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 2%;
}

.adds {
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 24%;
  border-left: 2px solid silver;
}

.adds img {
  border: 2px solid silver;
  margin-bottom: 15%;
  user-select: none;
  margin-left: 3%;
}

.bigArticle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.article {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 2% 5%;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="bigArticle">
        <h1>Блок 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="article" style="background: green;">
          <h1>Блок 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="article" style="background: #0C66E0;">
          <h1>Блок 3</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="adds">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://st2.depositphotos.com/2001755/5408/i/450/depositphotos_54081723-stock-photo-beautiful-nature-landscape.jpgg" alt="">
      </a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/2290789/3667/i/450/depositphotos_36675429-stock-photo-king-lion-aslan.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    </body
```

Ссылка на codepen: [Ссылка](https://codepen.io/egor977/pen/dyyRaPV?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перенесите медиазапросы в конец файла и всё заработает.
Это называется [каскадирование](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/kaskadirovanie).

Answer (score 0):

Это вообще не так делается. Вот так поправьте - https://codepen.io/aliencash/pen/MWWoLQj?editors=1100

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .adds {
    display: none;
  }
}

body>.row {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 2%;
}
```